# Linq to Entities DateTime Conversion

Tags: linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

If given an entity with a DateTime as a string, what are my options to filter the data with LINQ to Entities on the date?

It does not seem to support me doing DateTime conversions.

Basically, I want to accomplish:

```
var filtered = from item in entities.itemsSet
               where Convert.ToDateTime(shift.starttime) >= startDate 
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(shift.endtime) < endDate
               select item;
```

What are my options to accomplish this?

Comment: what kind of error are you getting, if any?

Comment: Basically along the lines of "Linq to entities does not support (Convert.ToDateTime(String)) ... "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to end up doing in memory filtering.

```
//So first select your data

var data= (from item in entities.itemsSet).ToList();


//Then filter
var filtered = from item in data
           where Convert.ToDateTime(shift.starttime) >= startDate 
               && Convert.ToDateTime(shift.endtime) < endDate
           select item;
```

Another option would be to create a stored procedure to do it for you.  In the SP you would have to take start/end and then compare it to your date time strings casted as Date Times.

Comment: I like this. While there may be issues with scaling, this will work. SP way is probably the way to go.

Comment: Completely agreed, but the first battle would be to change the DB type to date time!

Comment: And just as an fyi the code above can be simplified into one query.... 

by just doing var filtered = (select item from entities.itemsSet.AsEnumarable()

Comment: I can't change the DB type to time because the "client" has it that way =)

Comment: And we only have readonly access to it, as they aren't going to change their schema.

Comment: After the in-memory filtering, how do you convert back to LINQtoEntities? Since the .ToList() basically just converted to LINQtoObjects.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question?  They will still be entities, when i said turn them into objects i mean go ahead and select them from the database, then filter.

Comment: Great.... I have tried so many times using Convert.TodateTime in my linq to entites query but it doesn't work for me ......

Answer (score 6):

Use System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions

There is a function called DateDiff which has overloads to accept strings as dates.

All of the functions inside of the SqlFunctions class compile into SQL statements, and can only be used inside of Linq to entities.

```
[EdmFunctionAttribute("SqlServer", "DATEDIFF")]
public static Nullable<int> DateDiff(string datePartArg, string startDate, string endDate)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158.aspx

You will need to pass in a string like "day" as the first parameter specifying the part of the date to compare. The function directly maps to the SQL function DATEFIFF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

There is a similar class for Linq to SQL, just warning you.

Comment: Neato! This saved my bacon when using linq-to-entities to query for a date comparison on dates stored in a varchar column.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because the current Sql Server Data Provider for EF neglects to translate DateTime.Parse into CAST(varField As DateTime).

So to build up an Expression Tree which could be successfully translated into a Store Expression, I applied the following which behaves the same as one would expect from the predicate:  DateTime.Parse(x.DateField) == DateConstraint

NOTE That the 'Client' object contains the input parameters to produce a Predicate for use in: EFQuery.Where(predicate)

```
if (client.DateOfBirth.HasValue) // can't find a string <-> DateTime conversion syntax with EF support

         {

            var day = client.DateOfBirth.Value.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

            var month = client.DateOfBirth.Value.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

            var year = client.DateOfBirth.Value.Year.ToString();

            // very verbose, but apparently there's no EF support for String to DateTime conversion

            spec = spec.And(c => SqlFunctions.IsDate(c.DateOfBirth).HasValue && SqlFunctions.IsDate(c.DateOfBirth).Value == 1

               && c.DateOfBirth.StartsWith(day)

               && month == (c.DateOfBirth.Contains("-") || c.DateOfBirth.Contains("/")

               ? c.DateOfBirth.Substring(c.DateOfBirth.Contains("-") ? c.DateOfBirth.IndexOf("-") + 1 : c.DateOfBirth.Contains("/")

               ? c.DateOfBirth.IndexOf("/") + 1 : 0, 2) : "f")

               && c.DateOfBirth.EndsWith(year));

         }
```

As you can see, the above performs string matches on the Day, Month, and Year components of the dates, and expects a DD/MM/YYYY representation (Aussie Aussie Aussie!). It could easily be modified to work with different date representations and/or include constraints for the Time component also.