# finally the member age is not workng

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to check for people in a certain range - let minage and maxage corresponding for e.g. age group with minage=18 and maxage =24 meaning I am trying to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24.Also datatype for dob of member is string ..

i am trying this

```
 int agefrom = Convert.ToInt32(cbGEFrom.Text);
 int ageto = Convert.ToInt32(cbGETo.Text);
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
 DateTime max = today.AddYears(-(agefrom + 1));
 DateTime min = today.AddYears(-(ageto));
 string maxage = Convert.ToString(max);
 string minage = Convert.ToString(min);


var members = 
          from report in eclipse.members 
          where string.Compare(report.member_Dob,minage) >=0
          where string.Compare(report.member_Dob,maxage) < 0
        select report;
```

I have tried this below

```
 var members = from report in eclipse.members
      let dob =  DateTime.Parse(report.member_Dob) // or use ParseExact 
      where  dob >= minDOB && dob < maxDOB 
      select report;
```

but linq to entities does not support this line

```
let dob =  DateTime.Parse(report.member_Dob) // or use ParseExact
```

unfortunately the datatype for member_dob is string , i cant change the schema...

would any one pls give any idea for doing this...

Comment: You can't change the schema, but can you add a function to the db?

Comment: I would probably create a view in the db of that table that converts the string to a date, and than add that view to the linq context file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post [Linq to Entities DateTime Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555927/linq-to-entities-datetime-conversion)

I think it has the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the sql that is generated by this expression and all your string values are valid DateTime's you can do this:

```
var members = from report in eclipse.members
              let dob = eclipse.members.Take(1).Select(x => report.member_Dob).Cast<DateTime>().FirstOrDefault()
              where  dob >= minDOB && dob < maxDOB 
              select report;
```

Comment: @Magnus - This only works if all the Strings can be converted to the desired type. It will work with Integers, Doubles, and DateTimes

Comment: @Magnus - Entity Framework allows casting enumerable sequences, but not indvidual values. So I am creating an enumerable with only my one desired item, casting it, and then returning it as a value

Comment: `eclipse.members.Take(1)` always take the same value? And than you select `x` and never use it?

Comment: @Magnus - I am just using that to create an Enumerable, I am only interested in casting *report.member_Dob* to a DateTime. Ideally I would be able to do *DateTime.Parse(report.member_Dob)*, but EF doesn't support it