# Convert string to DateTime using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, type-conversion

I have a `Members` table with a column containing date of birth; by default the datatype for the `dateofbirth` column is `varchar`.

How can I convert the string to a `DateTime` using Entity Framework?

I have tried something like this:

```
let dob = eclipse.members.Take(1)
                         .Select(x => report.member_Dob)
                         .Cast<DateTime>()
                         .FirstOrDefault()
```

But it does not work for me and I can't change the schema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555927/linq-to-entities-datetime-conversion  check this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, L2E does not support any string to DateTime conversions. There are a couple workarounds, such as parsing the string and creating a DateTime object inside the Linq query to compare against, but those are verbose and ugly.

I'd suggest creating your L2E query as best you can, then use Linq to Objects to return your final dataset.

Answer (score -1):

what about this:

```
let dob =eclipse.members.Take(1).Select(x=> DateTime.Parse(report.member_Dob)).FirstOrDefault();
```

?

Comment: same error .....LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression