# Comparing dates in LINQ which are stored as strings in database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a database with content, designed to be very generic. One of the columns is MetaTag1, of type nvarchar(255), which contains dates in string format. I can't change this to DateTime type. I use Entity Framework code first to query the table with LINQ.

Now I have to do something like:

```
 var dateAsString = "12/04/2015";
 var result = context.MetaTags.Where(mt => DateTime.Parse(dateAsString) > DateTime.Parse(mt.MetaTag1));
```

This doesn't work, as I get the exception:

```
 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

One solution would be to first materialize the results in memory with ToList() and do the filtering in LINQ to entities. But this means that all results have to be retrieved first.

Is there another way to compare strings as dates in LINQ?

Thanks!

Comment: I take it the string in the database is stored in the stupid format "12/04/2015" as well?

Comment: It may be possible to use a direct a string comparison.  Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740693/big-issue-in-converting-string-to-datetime-using-linq-to-entities

Comment: @gregmac: We could agree on a format that consumers must use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entities DateTime Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555927/linq-to-entities-datetime-conversion)

Comment: @JasonBoyd: my question is not about LINQ to entities.

Comment: @L-Three You are using LINQ to query Entity Framework.  The error even contains 'LINQ to Entities' in it.  Your question is related to LINQ to entities.  See the chosen answer in the link I provided but also look at the answer with the highest votes (which happens to not be the chosen answer).

Comment: Ok I will check tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: You can move your comparison into an Expression that Linq can use.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618035/49251

Comment: If you can actually use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`YYYY-MM-DD`) then it sorts lexicographically, which means string comparison of dates in this format work without any conversion. It's part of the reason it's [so popular](https://xkcd.com/1179/) in computing. Of course, if you can change that format, I'm not sure why you can't just use a native Date type..

Comment: @JasonBoyd: just to let you know that the DateDiff method works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like:

```
 var result = context.MetaTags.Where(mt => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", mt.MetaTagFilter1, keyValueMetaTagFilter.MetaTagValue) <= 0);
```

Dates have to be stored in database in format "YYYY-MM-DD".